# Use ffmpeg example remuxing.c to record rtmp live stream to mp4 file, it add an empty elst box, how to forbid it?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mp4

Use ffmpeg example remuxing.c to record rtmp live stream to mp4 file, it add an empty elst box, how to forbid it?

The final MP4 file is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Only way to disable elst (without modifying ffmpeg code of course) is to disable whole edts tag. You can use use `-use_editlist 0` option to do that.